# If $X$ is standard exponential, explain why $2e^{-X}+1$ is uniform on $(1,3)$ while I find that $3-2e^{-X}$ is

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

> If $X\sim\text{Exp}(1)$, find a function $g$ so that $Y=g(X)$ is uniformly distributed over $(1,3)$.

I first tried to map $X$ onto $U\sim \text{Unif}(0,1)$, so that $X = F^{-1}(U)$ and $U=F(X).$

So I set $u=1- e^{-x}$ and found that $x=-\ln(1-u)$ for the inverse CDF.

I then tried to shift and scale $\text{Unif}(0,1)$ to $\text{Unif}(1,3)$ by stating that $½(Y-1)=U$ and plugged that into $u$ in the inverse function $x=-\ln(1-u).$

My answer turned out to be $Y=3 - 2e^{-X}$ but the correct solution is $Y = 2e^{-X} + 1$.

Can anyone please explain what I did wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$U\sim \text{Uniform}(1,3) \iff 4-U\sim \text{Uniform}(1,3)$

So both your answer and the answer in the book are correct.

What probably happened with the answer in the book is that instead of $F(X)=1-e^{-X}\sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$, they took  $1-F(X)=e^{-X}\sim\text{Uniform}(0,1)$ as well.

Comment: Thanks! A sidenote in the book says that we should assume x = -ln(u), whereas I found that x = -ln(1-u) by taking the inverse function of u=1-e^(-x). Why can we assume that x = -ln(u)?

Comment: Because if $U$ is Uniform$(0,1)$ then $1-U$ is Uniform$(0,1)$ as well.

Comment: ... and when an Exponential random variable is generated, $-\ln(U)$ is simpler than $-\ln(1-U)$ (by one subtraction), so it is the preferred method.